# Unable to use Jakarta instead of Javax when creating a SOAPConnectionFactory

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, soap

A little bit of context :
My Java project used to write data in a local database, but now we are moving to a SAAS solution. Sadly, the API we are going to use can only be called via SOAP. That means I am changing all of my writers so they can create and send appropriate SOAP envelopes.
Since I had no knowledge of how SOAP worked, I made a little side project as a POC to test out how the libraries worked. I used Maven to import the dependencies, and started using **javax.xml.soap**, but then I read that this library is very deprecated, so instead I switched to **jakarta**
And it worked ! My POC send the right envelopes and got a response. So I started adapting my big project, and I added that to my pom.xml :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.xml.ws-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.soap</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.xml.soap-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj</groupId>
        <artifactId>saaj-impl</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

And I adapted the code from my POC to the main project :

```
try {
        // Create SOAP Connection
        SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();

        MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();

        //Abstract method that needs to be overridden by each writer
        createSoapEnvelope(soapMessage, itemProcessorResult);

        MimeHeaders headers = soapMessage.getMimeHeaders();
        headers.addHeader("SOAPAction", soapAction);

        soapMessage.saveChanges();

        SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(
                soapMessage,
                ENDPOINT_URL
        );
```

I don't post the whole createSoapEnvelope, because it's big, but it looks like this :

```
 @Override
protected void createSoapEnveloppe(SOAPMessage soapMessage, ItemProcessorResult itemProcessorResult) throws SOAPException {

    SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();

    // SOAP Envelope
    SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
    envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration(namespaceShort, namespaceURI);

    // SOAP Body
    SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();
[A whole bunch of SOAPElements with addChildElement()]
```

After a **mvn clean install**, I could run my code, but I got errors at the execution

> javax.xml.soap                           : Using deprecated META-INF/services mechanism with non-standard property: javax.xml.soap.MetaFactory. Property javax.xml.soap.SAAJMetaFactory should be used instead.
> com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.impl     : SAAJ0101 : le parent dun élément SOAPBodyElement doit être un élément SOAPBody

It's strange that the error is in my system's language, and it means **"The parent of a SOAPBodyElement must be a SOAPBody element"**

I tried to fix that, but couldn't find anything. Then I noticed that the library used for the **SOAPConnectionFactory** was not the same in my POC and in the final project, by highlighting the class in IntelliJ

In my POC :
[POC library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXW3k.png)

In my project :
[Project library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8MuQ.png)

So my POC is using **jakarta**, but my project is still using **javax**. I tried to delete javax from my project by removing the dependency from my pom.xml (both of them, the main one and the module's one), but somehow the library is still there and used, even after reloading the project dependencies and doing some mvn clean install several times.

I am assuming my problem comes from the fact that I'm using the wrong library, but maybe I'm wrong ? And if I'm not, how can I set the library right ? I'm using the latest version of **IntelliJ** and have been fiddling with the projet properties, but I don't know much about it.

Oh, and both the POC and the project have

```
import javax.xml.soap.*;
```

on top. I tried to replace it with **jakarta.xml.soap.*** but it's just not compiling

Thank you (and sorry if I made any errors, english is not my native language and my brain is fried)

UPDATE : I changed my pom.xml to exclude javax.xml.soap, and now my SOAPConnectionFactory uses jakarta ! I still got my french error though.